# Making action after filtering data

Tags: javascript

I'm filling data to an array. I make many requests to a DB in postgress and I want to response the finished array to the client. The issue is that I can't reach when notifications array is complete, how can I know when filter has finished making all the select calls to db?

```
result.filter(function(item){
                //console.log(item.followed_by)
                var query2 = 'SELECT user_id,action,date,element_refered FROM "notifications" WHERE user_id=' + "'"+ item.followed_by +"'"

                dbp.sendDBRequest(query2,'blabla',function(results){
                 notifications.push(results)
                  console.log(notifications)  //here has data
               })
             })
console.log(notifications)  //here it doesnt have data
```

I tried with promises bt think I did it wrong:

```
           var p1 = new Promise(
    function(resolve, reject) {
   result.filter(function(item){
            var query2 = 'SELECT user_id,action,date,element_refered FROM "notifications" WHERE user_id=' + "'"+ item.followed_by +"'"
            dbp.sendDBRequest(query2,'blabla',function(results){
             notifications.push(results)
           })
         })

          resolve(notifications);
    }
  );

   p1.then(
    function(val) {
      console.log(notifications)
    })
  .catch(
    function(reason) {
      console.log('Manejar promesa rechazada ('+reason+') aquí.');
    });
```

Edit code:

This is the code with promises but I got then is not a filter(...).then is not a function

```
   var notifications = []
          var query = 'SELECT followed_by FROM "relations" WHERE follower=' +"'"+32+"'"
          dbp.sendDBRequest(query,'blabla', function(result) {
            result.filter(function(item) {
             return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
               var query2 = 'SELECT user_id,action,date,element_refered FROM "notifications" WHERE user_id=' + "'" + item.followed_by + "'"
               dbp.sendDBRequest(query2, 'blabla', function(results) {
                notifications.push(results);
                resolve(notifications);
             })
            })
             .then(function(val) {
               console.log(notifications)
            })
             .catch(function(reason) {
               console.log('Manejar promesa rechazada (' + reason + ') aquí.');
            });
          })
            .then(function(response){
             var secondResponse = response + '2';
             return response;
          })
            .then(function(secondResponse) {
  //facultad
})
            .catch(function(err){
               console.log(err)    
            })

         })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need promise inside your main function and it will return promise object.

```
result.filter(function(item) {
  new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var query2 = 'SELECT user_id,action,date,element_refered FROM "notifications" WHERE user_id=' + "'" + item.followed_by + "'"
      dbp.sendDBRequest(query2, 'blabla', function(results) {
        notifications.push(results);
        resolve(notifications);
      })
    })
    .then(function(val) {
      console.log(notifications)
    })
    .catch(function(reason) {
      console.log('Manejar promesa rechazada (' + reason + ') aquí.');
    });
})
```

Then you can handle then and catch blocks. 
Also if you want to continue, you can return that Promise object and add additional then...catch at the end

```
result.filter(function(item) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var query2 = 'SELECT user_id,action,date,element_refered FROM "notifications" WHERE user_id=' + "'" + item.followed_by + "'"
      dbp.sendDBRequest(query2, 'blabla', function(results) {
        notifications.push(results);
        resolve(notifications);
      })
    })
    .then(function(val) {
      console.log(notifications)
    })
    .catch(function(reason) {
      console.log('Manejar promesa rechazada (' + reason + ') aquí.');
    });
})
.then(function(response){
  var secondResponse = response + '2';
  return response;
})
.then(function(secondResponse){
  ...    
})
.catch(function(err){
   console.log(err)    
})
```

UPDATE

I think this will do what you are trying to accomplish

```
var notifications = [];

var pMain = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  var query = 'SELECT followed_by FROM "relations" WHERE follower=' + "'" + 32 + "'"
  dbp.sendDBRequest(query, 'blabla', function(result) {
    resolve(result);
  })
});

pMain.then(function(p1Result) {
  var promises = [];

  p1Result.forEach(function(item) {
    return promises.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var query2 = 'SELECT user_id,action,date,element_refered FROM "notifications" WHERE user_id=' + "'" + item.followed_by + "'"
      dbp.sendDBRequest(query2, 'blabla', function(results) {
        resolve(results);
      });
    }));    
  });
  return Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
    notifications.push(results);
  }).then(function(){
    console.log(notifications);
  });
})
```

Comment: ok thanks for the response, it returns TypeError: result.filter(...).then is not a function I added the code complete

Comment: Ah! my bad. then..catch should be after Promise. see the updated code

Comment: I am not sure how you handle errors in that sql function but, in order to fall in catch blocks, you need to add reject(error) to somewhere in main Promise.

Comment: Ok, added some new code. I think forEach would be a better fit for what you are trying to accomplish, rather than filter. Because filter should return true/false to reduce array.